# if field exist in database, then update price else insert all

Tags: php, mysql, simplexml

i need somehow to check if field exist in db, and then if exist, just update price, if not, insert fields. I am using simplxml for parsing data to db from xml.

here is my code without if statement, just insert into two databese.

I need to check from db `products` if `ident` exist, so if not exist, do all that code down, if exist just update `price` in db `products`

```
foreach ($lib->product as $data) {
    $manufacturer = (string) $data->manufacturer;
    $ident = (string) $data->id;
    $name = (string) $data->name;
    $category = (string) $data->category;
    $subcategory = (string) $data->subcategory;
    $price = (int) ($data->price * 1.2 * 1.4 * 1.1);
    $image = (string) $data->images->image[0];


    $insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO products (ident, manufacturer,name,category,subcategory,price,image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $insert->bind_param('sssssss', $ident, $manufacturer, $name, $category, $subcategory, $price, $image);
    $insert->execute();


    foreach($data->specifications->attribute_group as $group) {
        $attribute_group = (string) $group->attributes()['name'];

        foreach($group as $attr) {
            $attribute = (string) $attr->attributes()['name'];
            $value = (string) $attr->value;
            $insert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO spec (attr_group,attr_name, attr_value, product_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
            $insert->bind_param('ssss', $attribute_group, $attribute, $value, $ident);
            $insert->execute();

        }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do in one query, look up MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` functionality for `INSERT`.

Then use `$insert->rowCount()` if you're using **PDO** or `$insert->affected_rows` for **mysqli**.

If the first insert tried to already insert a key that existed and updates a value, then `rowCount()/affected_rows` will be **2**; if it just inserted a record then `rowCount()/affected_rows` will be **1**. It will be **0** if the `INSERT` was unsuccessful.

e.g. for **PDO**:

```
switch($insert->rowCount()) {
    case 2:  // UPDATE occurred thanks to 'ON DUPLICATE UPDATE KEY'
        // SOME CODE HERE IF YOU LIKE
        break;
    case 1:  // INSERT occurred as no duplicate
        // CODE TO INSERT INTO SECOND TABLE
        break;
    case 0:
    default:
        // NEITHER THE ABOVE OCCURRED SO CODE TO HANDLE ERROR
}
```

Comment: ok, that's work on table 'products' but i have another loop for table 'spec' where 'ident' cant be unique, because it is reapating. I need somehow when is ident duplicate on table 'products' then do nothing on table 'spec'

Comment: Is there a combination of columns that will be unique? If so, you can set a UNIQUE index on 2 or more columns.

Comment: A better understanding of your tables will help answer. You could edit your question or create a sqlfiddle.com and provide a link to it here

Comment: i am not sure that i understand you, but table look something like this when populate: http://www.odmaraj.com/me/image.jpg

Comment: Which table is this? There's no IDENT or PRICE columns in that table. Are there more tables?

Comment: yes, that is second table called 'spec', you have in code in my question

Comment: I assume spec.product_id = products.ident is the relationship between these two tables?

Comment: last answer is mistake, to spec.product_id and products.ident i insert same value, but i didnt create relationship. i am not sure how that work.

Comment: I think I now understand, I have updated my answer above to provide further instruction.

Comment: i tried your code, but i got this error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::rowCount()

Comment: I had assumed you were using PDO not mysqli. For mysqli use $insert->affected_rows. I will edit my answer...

Comment: bind_param not bindParam should've been the clue. I've just been working too much with PDO lately :S

Comment: thank you very much and sorry for all this long writing. As i said i am still leraning this.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to have helped. We all start somewhere and we never stop learning!

Answer (score 0):

```
        $query = "SELECT * name FROM yourtable";
        $bool = true;
            if($r = @mysql_query($query))
            {
                while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($r))
                {
                    if( ($row['id'] == $id))
                    {
                        $bool = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }               
            }

            if($bool) {
                UPDATE
            }
            else
            {
                INSERT
            }
```

Comment: i tried this code, but price is allways last one, it is not updating as it should. can you see my code and then write it with yours, i am not sure i did it right. thx

Comment: what do you mean by 'price is always last one'

Comment: i see your code and i see that you try to insert to table with 7 column  with bind_param with 8 column

Comment: i count it 7, i am not sure where did you see bind param 8 column? when i start this code in database all fields price are same

Comment: what is the error or bug you got when you use this code

Comment: i dont have error message, it is problem when it come to update, it is not updating as it should, ident = $price. For all rows i got same price